# I need to set a really specific regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas, mapping

I have a pandas dataframe with values on each cell like this:

```
GRI 101: Foundation: 
•  Clause 1.1 (Stakeholder Inclusiveness principle)
•  Clause 1.3 (Materiality principle)
•  Clause 2.1 (Applying the Reporting Principles)
GRI 102: General Disclosures: Disclosures 102-40, 102-42, 102-43, and 102-44
```

By using:

```
df['column'].str.findall(r'\d+-\d+').str.join('\n')
```

I am able to get the values:

```
102-40
102-42
102-43
102-44
```

Which is good, but apart from those values I got, I need a way to also extract the the 101 and append the clauses you see in the text. I need to be able to also gather those values and get something like this:

```
102-40
102-42
102-43
102-44
101-1.1
101-1.3
101-2.1
```

Not sure if it is possible, the reason for this is I have tons of values like this and I need to get them to use them then as reference to be able to perform a relationship between two ESG standards based on those values.

Comment: Can you share a larger snippet of your input ? If the pattern just repeats itself with the word "Clause" always preceding, then I guess regex alone won't help you. You'll need to stitch some strings to get the desired format, I can try to help if you can provide a larger snippet to help test what I have in mind.

Comment: The pattern always mention clause on the cell values that are as the one shown on the snippet, it is my first time trying to do something like this, I mean finding two numbers e.g 101 and 1.1 and then getting them like 101-1.1 as shown on the desired output snippet. I can make a loom video to show you in order to be more clear in my problem if you want. by the way thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

See if this work:

```
Disclosures = df['0'].str.findall(r'\d+-\d+').str.join('\n')[0]
top_number = str(df['0'].str.findall(r'GRI \d+').str.join('')).split('GRI')[1].strip()
clauses = str(df['0'].str.findall(r'[\d+][.][\d+]').str.join(' ')[0]).split(' ')
for c in clauses:
    print(top_number, '-', c, sep='')
print(Disclosures)
```

Here is my code example:

```
d = {'0': ["""GRI 101: Foundation: 
•  Clause 1.1 (Stakeholder Inclusiveness principle)
•  Clause 1.3 (Materiality principle)
•  Clause 2.1 (Applying the Reporting Principles)
GRI 102: General Disclosures: Disclosures 102-40, 102-42, 102-43, and 102-44""", "b"], '1': [3, 4], '2': [4, 5], '3': [7,8], '4': [9,10], '5': [12,13], '6': [15,17]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
Disclosures = df['0'].str.findall(r'\d+-\d+').str.join('\n')[0]
top_number = str(df['0'].str.findall(r'GRI \d+').str.join('')).split('GRI')[1].strip()
clauses = str(df['0'].str.findall(r'[\d+][.][\d+]').str.join(' ')[0]).split(' ')
for c in clauses:
    print(top_number, '-', c, sep='')
print(Disclosures)
```

output:

```
101-1.1
101-1.3
101-2.1
102-40
102-42
102-43
102-44
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import re


def process(x):
    first = re.search(r"\d+", x).group(0)
    disclosures = re.findall(r"\d+-\d+", x)
    clauses = re.findall(r"Clause (\d+\.\d+)", x)

    return "\n".join(
        ["\n".join(disclosures), "\n".join(f"{first}-{c}" for c in clauses)]
    )


df["result"] = df["column"].apply(process)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | column | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | GRI 101: Foundation: | 102-40 |
|  | • Clause 1.1 (Stakeholder Inclusiveness principle) | 102-42 |
|  | • Clause 1.3 (Materiality principle) | 102-43 |
|  | • Clause 2.1 (Applying the Reporting Principles) | 102-44 |
|  | GRI 102: General Disclosures: Disclosures 102-40, 102-42, 102-43, and 102-44 | 101-1.1 |
|  |  | 101-1.3 |
|  |  | 101-2.1 |